# Dragging and resizing floating windows in xmonad without the  modkey

Tags: xmonad, haskell

In my `.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file, I have the following lines, which control howto drag and resize windows. How can I change this, such that I don't need any mod key?

```
myMouseBindings (XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

    -- mod-button1, Set the window to floating mode and move by dragging
    [ ((modm,button1), (\w -> focus w >> mouseMoveWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button2, Raise the window to the top of the stack
    , ((modm,button2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- mod-button3, Set the window to floating mode and resize by dragging
    , ((modm,button3), (\w -> focus w >> mouseResizeWindow w
                                       >> windows W.shiftMaster))

    -- you may also bind events to the mouse scroll wheel (button4 and button5)
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `modm` with `0`, e.g.

```
, ((0,button2), (\w -> focus w >> windows W.shiftMaster))
```

(see [this documentation for and example `modKey`-less mouse binding](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Extending.html#g:13)).

**But** be aware that if you set a binding for `(0,button1)`, your *ordinary mouse clicks* probably won't reach the GUI program anymore (I never tried it) .

[Have a look at the `BorderResize` layout modifier, too.](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-BorderResize.html) (Note its dependence on a floating layout etc, see the first paragraph of the linked page.)

Comment: Thanks, but you are right, my ordinary mouse clicks don't reach the GUI after changing this...